# Attach JSON data to be used by view in MVC application

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a very simple application that I am using to learn move about MVC. In that application I search some data and return a JSON string that I want to use as the model for the view. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the view to consume the JSON as a set of data for it to show on screen.

The code I have so far:

```
Function Find(term As String) As ActionResult

    Dim model As String = SearchData(term)

    Return View(model)
End Function
```

SearchData returns a JSON string that can have one or many objects in it.

How do I now take the JSON returned from SearchData and use it in a view? In fact, when I attempt to add a view it wants to know what model to use. How do i also specific that?

Comment: Create a strongly typed class to hold the data, parse the JSON into your strongly typed model and pass that to the view. Let the view know to expect the strongly typed model.

Comment: Not entirely sure of your use case here, but if this is ASP.NET MVC that you are learning, consider that you need to return a model to your view from your controller action.  It looks like you know this bit already.  However, instead of returning a string to your view, I would be looking to return a custom object, or a collection of objects that you can then use in your razor view as your @model.  To get from the JSON string returned from SearchData(), to a collection of objects, look up details on JSON serialization to objects.  hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a strongly typed object to store you data when parsed

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Term As String
    Public Property SomeProperty As String
    Public Property SomeOtherProperty As String
End Class
```

Using a library like JSON.Net, parse the JSON returned from the search.

This assumes a collection of Data is returned from the search.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json;

Function Find(term As String) As ActionResult    
    Dim json As String = SearchData(term)
    Dim model As List(Of Data) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Data))(json)
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Let the view know to expect the strongly typed model.

```
@ModelType List(Of Data)
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Find"
End Code

<h2>MyView</h2>
<!-- rest of view where model can be accessed -->
```

Comment: people like you are why I  love this site! Thank you for the extremely helpful explanation. Your method works perfectly and I now understand how to make this work for other things moving forward.